# Multidimensional array structure like php print_r

Tags: jquery, ajax, multidimensional-array

I have form something like that:

```html
    <form id="incomes" method="post" action="#">
      <input type="text" name="date[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="income[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="tax[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="social_insurance[]"/>
      <input type="text" name="health_insurance[]"/>
    </form>
```

All I want to do is to post that inputs via jQuery ajax to php in structure like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        date => 2012-12-10
        income => 1000
        tax => 100
        social_insurance => 50
        health_insurance => 50
    )
    [1] Array(
        date => 2012-12-15
        income => 2000
        tax => 150
        social_insurance => 20
        health_insurance => 50
    )
)
```

Is there any simple way to achieve that? I've heard about serialize() function but that isn't what I want to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it myself all the time but I do it on the PHP side looping through an array:

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($_POST["date"] AS $i => $date) {
    $newarray[$i]["date"] = $date;
}
```

and so on..

So you keep sending your data via ajax as it is and do everything on server side, there you can sort and do whatever you need to the array before processing and outputting the result

Answer (score 0):

sending the form data using jQuery `serialize()` is simplest way to send the data. You would need to loop over the individual field arrays in php to create the array structure you want

```
$('#incomes').submit(function(){

    $.post(url, $(this).seralize(), function(response){
       /*run any  ajax complete code here*/
    }) ;
   /* prevent browser default form submit*/
   return false;

});
```

$_POST will look like:

```
  array(
      date=> array(),
       income=>array()/* etc*/
  }
```

PHP new array Loop could look something like:

```
$newArray=array();

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if( !empty( $value) && is_array($value)){
         for( $i=0;$i<count($value);$i++){
              $newArray[$i][$key]=$value[$i];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thats right, but we misunderstood. I don't want to get $_POST to looks like you send to me. Each field (ex. date, income, tax) should be connected with exactly index (like that structure I send in first post).


EDIT: Sorry mate... Just got my senses back... You're right. That should do the trick (about that foreach loop).

Comment: look at final loop... you have to restructure data somewhere..is easiest to do it in php but it could be done in javascript

Comment: I found something like that: ("#selector).map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get(); This will return the structure like charlietfl said without using serialize(). In php I'will handle with that.

Comment: that map won't create the key/values...have to create a javascript  object that contains arrays and code is just as easily accomplished using php loop I gave you

Comment: I did it with map function and it does create keys and values, I mean it's look like:

[date] => Array ( [0] => 2012-12-04 [1] => 2012-12-06 ) [income] => Array ( [0] => 5000 [1] => 2500)

Comment: what happens when you add more elements with same name?  Can do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cQpxL/1/

Comment: not sure whay you don't just use the php lloop..simple and clean

Comment: It's behave like I just posted before, any other item with same name is indexed with occurrence number between [] marks, like in php print_r version. For example we have 3 occurrences with income[] input field, output will looks like this: [income] => Array ([0] => val0 [1] => val1 [2] => val2)

Comment: I found that method somewhere and it's returning me an array that I could easily manage in php. Serialize function returning me an string looks like get request, I don't like it...

Comment: serialize returns just what any form post does. You just don't see it when a form is submitted conventionally. All data has to be sent to server as a string. GET just puts that string in url is only difference

Comment: Ok, I did it with serialize function. It's really simple and easy! Everything depends on proper loop in php. Thanks guys for your help!